# How can I delete an Ubuntu installation?

Tags: boot, 20.04, delete

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed it on my laptop twice. Every time I boot my computer it opens the 1st one I installed, which is the one in my HDD, so it's slower. How can I delete it? It's specifically located on sda5.

Comment: Are both the installations shown in the GRUB menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could understand, you have 2 different partitions/disks with Ubuntu, so you have 2 Ubuntu OS's on your laptop. Well, if they are on different disks, you can change the boot priority in the BIOS. If you have one disk and 2 partitions, just format the partition you don't want.

Hope it'd be helpful